# MongoDb subdocument query follows OR conditions?

Tags: mongodb

Consider the collection `orgs`:

```
db.orgs.save({"name":"bbc","people":[{"user_id":new ObjectId(),"role":"admin"},{"user_id":new ObjectId(),"role":"user"}]})
```

which is:

```
db.orgs.find().pretty()
```

of the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5316c81cb338e1a08a386367"),
    "name" : "bbc",
    "people" : [
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("5316c81cb338e1a08a386365"),
            "role" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("5316c81cb338e1a08a386366"),
            "role" : "user"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, if we query for `user_id:5316c81cb338e1a08a386366` and `role:admin`:

```
db.orgs.find({
                 "people.user_id":ObjectId("5316c81cb338e1a08a386366"),
                 "people.role":"admin"
             }).pretty()
```

It DOES finds the document (despite the fact that user_id `5316c81cb338e1a08a386366` has a role `user`).

Am I missing something ?

Because the [documentation example](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-multiple-fields) says:

> The following example uses dot notation to query for documents where
>   the value of the memos field is an array that has at least one
>   subdocument that contains the field memo equal to 'on time' and the
>   field by equal to 'shipping':

```
      db.inventory.find(
               {
                 'memos.memo': 'on time',
                 'memos.by': 'shipping'
               }
             )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```
db.orgs.find({ people: { $elemMatch: { user_id: ObjectId("5316c81cb338e1a08a386366"), role: 'admin' } } })
```

Comment: @Echo thats the point. The objectId is from the other entry in the array

Comment: @NeilLunn why you have deleted your own question? is there something wrong with it?

Comment: @Echo because I misread the question. The criteria are from two different documents in the array. The query is intended to **not** return everything.

Comment: @Pierre Thanks a lot. They should have clearly stated the difference in documentation.

Comment: You welcome, have used this one couple times myself ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just a bit of explanation: You are mixing normal queries with array queries.

Your query is **not only** going to return the documents having `user_id:5316c81cb338e1a08a386366` and `role:admin` in `people` array in the same index, but also return the documents having both of them but not in the same index of `people` array.

If you do a normal query on an array, it looks in the **entire** array and checks whether both of the criterion are present in the array. So in order to return `bbc` document, all u need to provide is a role-user_id pair that is present in the people array - index independet. If you want to have the desired behaviour then you should use @Pierre's answer, `$elemMatch`. Read the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/).

About the documentation example you ve provided, it does assume however that `memos` is not an array. If it would be an array then the same condition will hold.